# Re-indexed procedure in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, sql, reindex

If i update 10K products and re-indexed it first time it will re-indexed all.

**But if i update 10 more product so it will require re-index so my question is is it re-index all the products from starting and re-index 10k products or it will only re-index 10 products.**

Like wen i it re-index query and check my SQL sow processlist it will run from 1 or it will only re-index after 10k products.

Answer (score 0):

This docs is provide your answer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @viru
But it doesn't tell about if i re-index second time.